# How to show the product of a polynomial and a function in the schwarz space is also in the Schwartz space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

> **Definition 4.7.1.** To say that a continuous function $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ is rapidly decaying means that one of the following equivalent conditions (see Problem 4.7.1) holds:
>
> 1. For any $n \geq 0, x^{n} f(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbf{R}$.
> 2. For any $n \geq 0, \lim _{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} x^{n} f(x)=0$.
>
> In the language of asymptotics (Definition 3.6.7), the latter condition can be written as $f(x) \ll\left(1 / x^{n}\right)$, or in other words, as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty, f(x)$ goes to $0$ faster than any function $1 / x^{n}$.
>
> The Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{R})$ is the space of all $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ such that for all $k \geq 0$, the $k$ th derivative $f^{(k)}(x)$ of $f$ exists for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$ and is rapidly decaying.
>
> We have the following basic properties of Schwartz functions.

[Transcribed from screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w84U.png)

How do we show that for any polynomial $p(x)$, we have that $p(x)f(x)$ is also in the Schwartz space if $f(x)$ is in the Schwartz space. I have already shown that the sum and product of Schwartz function are Schwartz, and $p(x)f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable by the product rule so all its derivative satisfies the two condition of our definition if we can prove that $p(x)f(x)$ satisfies the conditions. To show that $p(x)f(x)$ is itself bounded, it is possible to use condition one for $f(x)$ and choose $x^n$ with degree larger than $p(x)$? Can we then say that $|p(x)f(x)|\leq |x^nf(x)|$ which would make $p(x)f(x)$ bounded? But even if that is proven though, I'm still not sure how we can prove $x^np(x)f(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: it follows immediately by the definition of a Schwartz function

Comment: My feeling: if you actually wrote out the calculations that you detailed, and understood them, in particular the step that "all its derivative satisfies the two condition", then you would have answered your own question. PS Schwarz and Schwartz are two different people